# WordPress 3.0 getting list of custom pages

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to get a list of all the pages of a certain custom page type I've defined into a  as you would with wp_list_pages?

Thanks a bunch,
-scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a variation of wp_query to generate a list?

```
<?php $mylist = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'mycustompagetype', 'posts_per_page' => 99 ) ); ?>

<?php while ( $mylist ->have_posts() ) : $mylist ->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title( '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></li>' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Think this would do?